Pyomo not respecting constraint
I'm having a problem and I'm hoping you could help me.
I have a constraint such as follows:
def grid_power_calculation_with_balance(model, t):
    if t == 0:
        return model.P_grid[t] == 0
    return model.P_grid[t] == model.PCh[t] - model.PDch[t] + \
              sum(model.gamma[i, t] * (cooling_capacity(value(model.T[i, t - 1])) / COP(value(model.T[i, t - 1])) * model.delta[i, t] + P_aux[i]) for i in I) - model.P_used_renew[t]
model.grid_power_calculation = Constraint(T,rule=grid_power_calculation_with_balance)

with such variables:
model.delta = Var(I, T, within=Binary)  # Decision variable: 1 if cooling, 0 if heating
model.P_used_renew = Var(T, within=NonNegativeReals)
def renew_usage_limit(model, t):
    return model.P_used_renew[t] <= renew[t]
model.renew_usage_limit = Constraint(T, rule=renew_usage_limit)

# Auxiliary variables for constraints
model.T = Var(I, T, bounds=lambda model, i, t: (LB[i], UB[i]), initialize=lambda model, i, t: initial_temperature[i])
model.P_grid = Var(T, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.gamma = Var(I, T, within=Binary)
model.PCh = Var(T, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.PDch = Var(T, within=NonNegativeReals)

Now, even though my model.P_grid is explicitly within=NonNegativeReals, I'm still getting constraints such as P_grid[36]  ==  -302.34367745743657.
I wondered if there was a problem with declaring decision variables the same way as auxiliary variables but that's actually what you are supposed to do with pyomo. Anyways, it's straight up violating the bounds of a variable so it should be considered an infeasible solution. Actually, it looks like it is rounding it to 0 instead of changing the values for it not to need to be rounded. It should probably even throw an infeasible if it were to need to go negative anyways (it doesn't)
I also don't believe there's any non-linearity with my modelling (besides "some" with COP and stuff which wasn't a problem). All the other variables should be obtained just by changing model.delta and model.P_used_renew. Thanks, if you need anymore info from me, be free to ask and thanks again!
PS: I'm using Gurobi, if that's relevant.

This is an "illegal" optimization.  You cannot ask for the value of a variable with value(), which you appear to be doing twice in the middle of a very non-linear expression
Realize that pyomo and other similar languages just formulate the problem in terms of constants and variables and then hand it to a solver, so there is no value() to pass.  You'll have to reformulate your constraint.

Thank you for your answer. Yep, I realized it was something like that.
Regarding the other possibility. I tried to do a Piecewise variable for both COP and Cooling Power. Still, it was a division between two variables, so instead I used a single Piecewise variable for the P_cool (cooling power/COP). Well, that became, still a non linear constraint. Would that be because it's a piecewise times a piecewise (the delta?).
My current solution was to simply use the initial temperature for COP and cooling power, and then rerun with a COP and cooling power for the solution (basically interpolate

I can then do that interpolation some times in order do better "perfect it".
